# Are there any packages lets one to learn shell interactively via terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, software-recommendation

I am looking for a package/application that runs without gui(through terminal) that will help me learn shell via providing instructions and informations regarding to the lesson topic by printing text to console, and accepting code as the answers and interpret it. I know there are some websites like [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com) that can help me , but these methods runs through an online, virtual(?) terminal, and can be laggy; not to mention so many bugs. Thus i want to practice shell in my own terminal.

Those who are familiar with R language, i am looking for something exactly like  [swirl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/swirl/index.html) package.

Are there any tools that will do what i described above?

Comment: I have searched around a fair bit but I couldn't find anything that meets all your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

`fish` is as close as possible to what you want. Simply install `fish` with:

```
sudo apt install fish
```

and run it:

```
fish
```

While it doesn't give you tutorials, it is by far the most beginner-friendly shell